# Should I download the information in controller or data class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

My application downloads photos from web server. Is downloading photo information from server Controller's business or data's business? I mean should I download data in controller class

```
Photo.title = [self getPhotoInfoFromServer: url];
```

or in data class?

```
[Photo getPhotoInfoFromServer: url];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Global point of view

An UIViewController is here to Control a View. It means interactions (give good data to the view, and answer to view interactions).

A model / an entity can be created by independents sources (unless the source itself is semantically linked with your model). A Photo is a Photo, whatever if created from a data retrieved from a server or from a local Camera Roll picture.

You should use a custom DataFetcherController to get a remote data and transform it into a instance.

#### Example Flow

Your `UIViewController subclass` needs a list of photos. It asks the `PhotoServerFetcherController` for getting the data from the Server. The fetcher can look into its cache and perfom a request the a server if needed. When the `PhotoServerFetcherController` get the data and parse it to instances of your `Photo` entity and give it back to the UIViewController`.

#### Data fetcher interactions

The best is to create your own `FetcherController`interface (`@protocol` keyword). You can handle 2 async callbacks : `success` with the data in it and `failure` with the error in it (connection ? bad input ?).

Here you have many ways to implements that, the main 2 patterns for 1 to 1 interactions are `delegate` or `block callbacks`.

Comment: `Photo *photo = [PhotoServerFetcherController getPhoto:url];` Does it work?

Comment: I'm going to make PhotoServerFetcherController singleton. Is it a a good idea?

Comment: As the data is always get from the same server source and/or if your photos are used through multiple screens in your app it's a good idea to have a Singleton!

Comment: Singleton is __usually__ a better option than static methods. But it depends on your flow.

Answer (score 1):

You should download the photos in to data class then the viewControllers those needs that data can easily get from data class. Actually you should follow MVC where

M= Modal (Your Data Class)

C= Controller class

V= view what your controller displays

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using a dedicated server class, which instantiates models, and is used from the controller: `[photoServer getPhotoFromURL:URL]`, or `[photoServer getPhotoFromURL:URL completion:^(Photo *photo, NSError *error){...}]`

Why a dedicated server class?

- photos may come from several sources, and you don't want to write many `+[Photo getPhotoFrom...]` methods and hinder the reusability and maintainability of your Photo class.
- Whenever the server implementation changes, you just have to modify a single class, the class which is responsible for the server. The Photo model remains unaware there is even a server, and is not concerned by the server implementation. This is the [principle of single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) in action.

Why should this code be called from the controller?

- server access is inherently asynchronous, and may fail. Only controllers know how to deal with delay and errors when we talk about user feedback.